# DKIM Record Not Working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, dkim

I was setup SPF, DKIM and DMARC Record for my mail server,
SPF and DMARC Record are working normally now,
But i got a problem for my DKIM Record,
When i do: **dig default._domainkey.example.com txt**
The DKIM Record is published, i got a return from dig like **v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa;p="HASH"**
But when i check it from mail-tester.com, i got **You're not fully authenticated, Your message is not signed with DKIM**
It's already been 24hours and i think my DKIM Record already propagated.What should i do for this DKIM Record?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Your message is not signed with DKIM" - means that your messages is not signed.

You have the record published, but your email-server does not sign the emails.

Comment: Great, it was solved by sign emails with DKIM